# is UID of mifare classic editable?

Tags: clone, nfc, uniqueidentifier, mifare, serial-number

It would be nice if `UID` is write-protected so that I can use it to detect card clones.
So, can it be modified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.  The standard Mifare Classic has a locked sector 0, where the UID is stored.  However, if you Google [changeable uid mifare](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&q=changeable+uid+mifare), you'll find several (comparatively expensive) cards for sale with sector 0 unlocked.

Comment: it depends on the manufacturer? manufacturer can choose whether to lock it, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the UID-s of the Mifare Classic are'nt guaranteed to be unique, so beware of that problem.